# Laravel Middleware | Вложенные промежуточные слои

Tags: laravel, middleware

Перефразирую вопрос на реальном примере.

У меня есть Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class EmailIsVerifiedOverride
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // TODO: Добавить проверку на верифицированность профиля.
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

В Laravel 6.0 (ниже не знаю) есть Auth в котором есть

```
'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class
```

Я делаю override данного компонента посредством создания нового слоя и видоизменяю поведение Kernel:

```
'verified.default' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
'verified' => \App\Http\Middleware\EmailIsVerifiedOverride::class,
```

Собственно я хочу в своем override'е использовать middleware и переопределять его.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class EmailIsVerifiedOverride
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $requireVerified = true;
        if ($requireVerified)
            $this->middleware('verified.default');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Подобно вот такому решению.

Comment: лучше приведите не рабочий код  , ото не понятно где вы его используете и про какой компонент идет речь

Comment: у данного класса нет метода middleware чтоб к нему обратиться через $this.
унаследуйте от вашего класса где он объявлен

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan извините, я перефразировал вопрос, так будет понятней!

Comment: верификацию можно проверить путем  `auth()->check()`.
Например `if(auth()->check()) return $next($request); else abort(401);`

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Мне нужно использовать middleware из EnsureEmailIsVerified и впихнуть в EmailIsVerifiedOverride, во втором куске кода я наглядно показал что хочу.

Comment: Попробуй в место $this->middleware... впихнуть этот кусок 
`return app(\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class)->handle($request, function ($request) use ($next) {
 return $next($request);
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class EmailIsVerifiedOverride:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $requireVerified = true;
        if ($requireVerified)
        {
            return app(\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class)
                    ->handle($request, function ($request) use ($next) { 
                                            return $next($request); 
                                        });
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```